# Badge for discarding question before posting

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

I was asking a question and while typing it thought of something new to try.

I tried it, it worked, so I discarded the question.

The question was not long, but it was of decent length.

I was thinking maybe a badge called "Actually..." or something similar where if a question of a sufficient length or time duration gets discarded.

Basically encouraging the act of not posting a question if you realize the answer while writing it.

I'd say it would be bronze and only awardable once.

Thoughts?

Comment: `Basically encouraging the act of not posting a question if you realize the answer while writing it.`  Do we have an abundant problem of people figuring out the answer to their question while writing it, and then posting the question anyway?  (If so, let's see some examples.)  In these (apparently common) instances are the questions actually low quality questions?

Comment: _"qwertyuiop * 100"_: Yay, free badge. What's the point?

Comment: That badge would be way too easy to earn for all those badge hunters

Comment: Ok, so bad idea...

Comment: @Floern Bronze badges are *supposed* to be trivial to earn if you're actually trying to game them.  Most of them are just "use this site feature for the first time" so that's not actually a problem.

Comment: Not necessarily "bad", but not "good", either ;-)

Comment: My question was about 15 min of type time. I guess I just wanted something for the time haha

Comment: @Cerbrus Scroll through the Tour site as fast as you can -> earned "Informed" badge. So there are other easy badges which can earned by some "tricks" :P.

Comment: @Servy yes, but in this case you wouldn't even need to do something productive to get the badge, just writing gibberish and then delete it again

Comment: @Floern I'm sure there is some way to screen for gibberish, min number of discrete unique words etc

Comment: for the many times I discarded a post I would be a gold badge holder now ...

Comment: @Floern You can do the same thing for autobiographer or commentator.

Comment: @rene well you would have a single bronze badge. I don't think it should stack or ever go silver or gold

Comment: @Servy I don't like that badge either :P

Comment: @Floern Again, it's basically the purpose of bronze badges.  They're designed to be "use this site feature".  They're not *supposed* to be any harder than "trivially easy" to earn.  There are problems with the proposal, but how easy it is to get isn't one of them.

Comment: Cross-site near duplicate: [Badge for not asking an already answered question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109724/168333)

Comment: No issues. When Getting enough downvotes, the OP will remove the question by himself

Answer (score -1):

This would be counterproductive for the site. SO aims to be a high quality QA site, and high quality questions are an essential part of that. Even if you do realise the answer while writing your question, DO post the question, but also click the checkbox at the bottom of the page saying *"Answer your own question – [share your knowledge, Q&A-style](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)"*, and then write the answer as well.